# TFS2012 permissions: how do I remove the user?

Tags: tfs

I once added a user to change permission on one specific project folder. Now he can inherit permission from its group and I simply wanted to remove him from the list. How do I remove this user from the permission management of that specific project folder?

I checked documentation but user removal is mentioned nowhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252470.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the web interface:

- Navigate to http://{yourtfs}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_admin/_security
- Click "Users" link at the top section of left pane
- Find the user and select it
- From the right pane, click the "Member of" link
- You can easily remove the user from the group you want by clicking "Remove" link next to a group

Comment: We need to change permissions on a specific project folder, not for the complete project